# AppRegistryNotReady when adding new app to django project

Tags: python, django

I am using `django` version 1.8.5
I created an `apps.py` for my app and I added `'contact.apps.ContactConfig'` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` but I am still getting a `AppRegistryNotReady`.

Here is the link to my project if I did not provide enough information:

https://github.com/liondancer/django-cherngloong/tree/master/server/contact

From my understanding, I need an `apps.py` in order to notify `Django` of my apps existence

Project structure:

```
/cherngloong
  /server
    __init__.py
    /cherngloong
      ...
      ...
      settings.py
    /contact
      __init__.py
      app.py
```

cherngloong/server/contact/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ContactConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "contact"
    verbose_name = "Contact"
```

/cherngloong/server/cherngloong/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webpack_loader',
    'contact.apps.ContactConfig'
)
```

I tried simply putting `'contact'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` but I get the same error. However, if I comment out `'contact'` my server runs

Traceback:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 177, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 72, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: What are you doing in contact itself? Is there any module-level code in models or views?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried moving everything OUT of my `server` folder and that removed the `AppRegistryNotReady` error. I also removed everything that had `server` in front of it. Example: `ROOT_URLCONF = 'cherngloong.urls'` was `'server.cherngloong.urls'`. I'm not sure why putting everything within a server directory caused issues even though I think I took account of everything being in `server` directory and added `server.` in front of everything